# Plotting Laplace's equation on an infinite domain

Tags: numerical-integration

I am trying to plot my solution to a Laplace equation on an infinite domain.  However, when I try to plot it, *Mathematica* just runs with nothing happening.

```
f[x_, y_] = Sinh[u*(5 - y)]/Sinh[u*5]*100/π*Cos[u*(ξ - x)]; 
DensityPlot[Integrate[f[x, y], {u, 1, 10}, {ξ, -5, 5}], {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 5}]
```

The code I have tried is above. The solution is 
$$
f(x, y) = \frac{100}{\pi}\int_0^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sinh(u(5-y))}{\sinh(5u)}\cos(u(\xi - x))d\xi du
$$

Comment: In general, if your integral is time consuming to calculate, it would be better to first evaluate it and then feed it to `DensityPlot`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks that didn't work either.

Comment: I have checked that this works, though it's not very fast : `f[x_, y_, u_, \[Xi]_] = 
 Sinh[u*(5 - y)]/Sinh[u*5]*100/\[Pi]*Cos[u*(\[Xi] - x)]`, `g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[f[x, y, u, \[Xi]], {u, 1, 10}, {\[Xi], -5, 5}]`, `DensityPlot[g[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 5]`.

Comment: @b.gatessucks I have been running the code for 12mins and still nothing though.

Comment: Perhaps you want to rephrase your question to be about [tag:performance-tuning] (how to speed up the process).

Answer (score 1):

This is what I get in under 5 minutes :

```
f[x_, y_, u_, \[Xi]_] =  Sinh[u*(5 - y)]/Sinh[u*5]*100/\[Pi]*Cos[u*(\[Xi] - x)] ;
g[x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ] := NIntegrate[f[x, y, u, \[Xi]], {u, 1, 10}, {\[Xi], -5, 5}]

DensityPlot[g[x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, 0, 5}, PlotPoints -> 5]
```

[image: 5 min]